# Python sdk OCI : Remove backup policy of boot volume

Tags: python-3.x, oracle-cloud-infrastructure, oci-python-sdk

How do we remove the assigned backup policy of boot volume attached to an instance using python sdk OCI package

Didn't find with UpdateBootVolume

https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/api/#/en/iaas/20160918/BootVolume/UpdateBootVolume

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can accomplish this:

1. Call this method from the OCI SDK to get BackupPolicyAssignment:

https://oracle-cloud-infrastructure-python-sdk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/core/client/oci.core.BlockstorageClient.html?highlight=Get_Volume#oci.core.BlockstorageClient.get_volume

2. Call this method to check if its the right volume for the above backup policy:

https://oracle-cloud-infrastructure-python-sdk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/core/client/oci.core.BlockstorageClient.html?highlight=Get_Volume#oci.core.BlockstorageClient.get_volume_backup_policy

3. Delete it to remove attachment policy to volume:

https://oracle-cloud-infrastructure-python-sdk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/core/client/oci.core.BlockstorageClient.html#oci.core.BlockstorageClient.delete_volume_backup_policy_assignment